# How to get the page calling the usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control .Is there some way to get the page in which usercontrol is available ?

Comment: The Page property stands for what you mean. Please give more detail about what you want to do with the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your usercontrol write this method

```
protected void MyMethod()
{
    Page myParent = this.Page;

    ... 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Best to use MyPage page = this.Parent as MyPage; in case the Page type isn't MyPage.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `Page` property.

If you need to write back to a page of a certain type, you'll have to cast:

```
var myUserPage = Page as MyCustomUserPageClass;
if (myUserPage != null) {
  myUserPage.Foo = "bar";
}
```